# Why am I getting 4 as output after running code in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
int main()
{
int *pnPtr = new int;
delete pnPtr;
*pnPtr = 4;
cout<<*pnPtr;
}
```

`Ans) 4` while I tried to execute in visual studio 2010.

Please, explain me how `4` is displayed as output?

Comment: It could display anything, it could even cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), please learn and read about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @sandeep Could one of the provided answers solve your understanding problem? If so, it would be great if you accepted one :)

Answer (score 4):

what did you expect it to return?

Understand, that delete only frees the allocated memory pointed at, but leaves the pointer as it is. You can still use the pointer to do something to the pointed address.

```
int main()
{
int *pnPtr = new int; // allocate memory, pnPtr now points to it
delete pnPtr; // delete allocated memory, pnPtr still points to that location
*pnPtr = 4; // set memory at pointed address to 4
cout<<*pnPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `pnPtr` still points to somewhere in memory, calling `delete` does not change the value of `pnPtr` itself. The memory is just no longer allocated for your process.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to `Dangling pointers` that arise during object destruction, when an object that has an incoming reference(pointer) is freed or de-allocated, **without modifying the value of the pointer**, so that the pointer still points to the memory location of the de-allocated memory.

Assume if the system reallocates the previously freed memory to another process, if the original program then de-references the (now) dangling pointer, **unpredictable behavior** may result, as the memory may now contain completely different data. This is especially the case if the program writes data to memory pointed by a dangling pointer a silent corruption of unrelated data may result, leading to:

1. Subtle bugs that can be extremely difficult to find, or
2. cause **segmentation faults** or
3. general **protection faults**.

So, it is recommended to reset the freed/deleted pointer as follows:

```
int main()
{
 int *pnPtr = new int;
 delete pnPtr;
 pnPtr = null;
 // To-do Logic
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete does not change the value of the pointer, it destroys the int size memory association but if not reallocated then it can be available. That has happened in your case.